# Change image in "slider" on hover li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I'm trying to create a "Slider" wich change the image when hovering over an li element. If you click on the link beneath you can see what i mean.

http://www.ing.nl/particulier/

```
<div id="infobyimage">
<div class="nav-blocks">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li> Geschilderd huis</li>
        <li> Steiger</li>
        <li> Houtrot pillen</li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="slider">
<ul>
    <li><img src="images/DSC00742-slide.png" alt="Geschilderd huis"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/DSC00752-slide.png" alt="Geschilderd huis"/></li>
</ul>
```

In the HTML above you can see that i'm trying to achieve the same as on the link. Can someone please explane how to do this with jquery or just CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to fix this with display none and on hover change the images to display block. But there always need to be one image on the screen so it didn't work out for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `.hover(function(){//content});` on the element that you want to change for example if you wanted a function for hovering over one element you would do:

```
$('.element').hover(function(){
$('.another_element').fadeOut(100);
});
```

This function says that when you hover over a div that has a class of element, it make another div that has a class of another-element `.fadeOut()` at 100 milliseconds and make the opacity of another-element 0. For this snippet of JQuery to work though you need to add an ajax file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RtAhx/)**

I change the `img attribute` when I hover particular `li` i.e.

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").hover(
 function () {     
  $('#changeImage').attr('src','source');
});
```